# How to save file with today's date?

Tags: save, date-and-time

I am trying to save a file with today's date as part of name.

To save file, we can just do `:w myFile`. To get today's date, we can use `strftime`. Ex: `:echo strftime("%F") " returns 2020-03-27`.

Now I would like to combine both - to save with today's date. Something like:

```
:w 'myFile-(strftime("%F")'
```

Is it possible to save file with today's date (`myFile-2020-03-27`.) in Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The first one is interactive, using [`CTRL-R =`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R_%3D) in the Ex command-line to enter an expression and evaluate it.

Start by typing the command as usual: `:w myFile-`, then press `CTRL-R`, `=`. You'll now have a `=` prompt where you can enter an expression. Enter `strftime("%F")` and press "Enter", Vim will evaluate that to 2020-03-27 (assuming that's today's date) and will now display the command-line as `:w myFile-2020-03-27`, which you can then execute or further edit as you like.

Another option is to use the [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aexecute) command to execute a string as an Ex command. In which case you can simply use:

```
:exe 'w myFile-'.strftime("%F")
```

Note that `.` is the string concatenation operator here. This latter form with `:execute` is particularly useful in Vim scripts or functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you frequently find yourself wanting to insert the current date into command-line commands you could set up a mapping like this using something similar to what's in the existing answer:

```
:cnoremap YMD <C-R>=strftime("%Y-%m-%d")<CR>
```

Your use case then would be to enter

```
:w myFile-YMD
```

Which, right after you hit <kbd>D</kbd>, will be converted to

```
:w myFile-2020-03-27
```

and then you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to submit it. I have this in my vimrc and it comes in handy.

Comment: I really like this idea in general. But I find that `:cabbrev <expr> YMD strftime("%F")` is a better way to implement it. Using a `cabbrev` means it won't make it awkward to type a single `Y` or `YM` on the command line. It will still properly expand if `YMD` appears after a `-`. Also using `<expr>` is much simpler than `<C-R>=` here, since it's possible to do so. One small downside of `cabbrev` is that it doesn't expand on `D`, so if you type `:w myFile-YMD<CR>` you won't "see" the date until the command is completed. You can work around that by expanding it explicitly with `<C-]>` though.

Comment: That's not my experience at all. Zero awkwardness. Have you tried it with `cnoremap`? Putting aside the fact that "Y" or "YM" (and, for many people I'd wager, capital letters in general) are used relatively infrequently on the command line there's no delay if I type something other than "MD"/"D" after them. Vim only waits if you wait. And then it only waits for however long you've configured. I have `'ttimeout'` enabled and `'ttimeoutlen'` set to  100 (these are also Vim's recommended values as you can see in defaults.vim). There's also no problem using "YMD" after a `-`. (cont)

Comment: And finally, I _like_ the value to be inserted immediately...not uncommon for me to flip the date to yesterday or tomorrow, for example, and I'd rather not stretch for a `<C-]>` if I don't have to.